# Updating a table in sql database

Tags: sql-server

I have the following requirement/business rule:
Galaxys

```
delete * from Galaxys
```

'append from ADE data - qryGetGalaModel

```
INSERT INTO tbl Galaxys ( [ID Number], [ID Status], [ Type], [ID Completed], [MK Link ID], [MODEL Link ID], [ID Main Vendor] )
SELECT Ceekay_ID_WO.TNE_NO, Ceekay _TNE_WO.STATUS, Ceekay_TNE_WO.TYPE, Ceekay _TNE_WO.TNE_ID_COMPLETED, Ceekay_TNE_WO.CS_LINK_ID, CStr([cs_link_id]) AS [User Link ID], Ceekay_TNE_WO.SUPPLIER
FROM Ceekay _TNE_WO
WHERE (((Ceekay _TNE_WO.STATUS)<>"CANC") AND ((Ceekay_TNE_WO.WORK_TYPE)="De-Install" Or (Ceekay_TNE_WO.WORK_TYPE)="MBNL-De-Install") AND ((Ceekay_TNE_WO.TNE_COMPLETED) Is Null Or (Ceekay_TNE_WO.TNE_COMPLETED)>=#7/1/2007#) AND ((Ceekay_TNE_WO.TNE_TYPE)="RADIO"))
ORDER BY Ceekay _TNE_WO.TNE_COMPLETED;
```

'add link ends - qryUpdateAandBends

```
UPDATE ((((tblGalaxys  INNER JOIN SPECTRUM_IQLINK ON tblGalaxys.[User Link ID] = Ceekay _IQLINK.LINK_ID) INNER JOIN Ceekay _LINK_END ON Ceekay_IQLINK.LINK_ID = Ceekay _LINK_END.LINK_ID) INNER JOIN Ceekay_LINK_END AS Ceekay _LINK_END_1 ON Ceekay _IQLINK.LINK_ID = Ceekay_LINK_END_1.LINK_ID) INNER JOIN (qryConvertSiteID AS qryConvertSiteID_1 INNER JOIN tbl CeekayLiteSiteDetails AS tbl CeekayLiteSiteDetails_1 ON qryConvertSiteID_1.Site_ID = tblCeekayLiteSiteDetails_1.Site_ID) ON Ceekay_LINK_END_1.SITE_ID = qryConvertSiteID_1.[site ID]) INNER JOIN (qryConvertSiteID INNER JOIN tblCeekayLiteSiteDetails ON qryConvertSiteID.Site_ID = tblCeekayLiteSiteDetails.Site_ID) ON SPECTRUM_LINK_END.SITE_ID = qryConvertSiteID.[site ID] SET tblGalaxys.[A Cell ID] = [tblCeekayLiteSiteDetails].[cell_id], tblGalaxys.[A Site ID] = [Ceekay_link_end].[site_id], tblGalaxys.[B Cell ID] = [tblCeekayLiteSiteDetails_1].[cell_id], tblGalaxys.[B Site ID] = [spectrum_link_end_1].[site_id]
WHERE (((Ceekay_LINK_END.END_ID)="A") AND ((Ceekay_LINK_END_1.END_ID)="B"));
```

'add site info - qryUpdateGalaxyDetails

```
UPDATE (((tblGalaxys INNER JOIN Ceekay_SITE ON tblGalaxys.[A Site ID] = Ceekay_SITE.SITE_ID) LEFT JOIN Ceekay_SITE AS Ceekay_SITE_1 ON tblGalaxys.[B Site ID] = Ceekay_SITE_1.SITE_ID) LEFT JOIN WurzelSitesProgUpdate ON tblGalaxys.[A Site ID] = WurzelSitesProgUpdate.[TM Site ID]) LEFT JOIN WurzelSitesProgUpdate AS WurzelSitesProgUpdate_1 ON tblGalaxys.[B Site ID] = WurzelSitesProgUpdate_1.[TM Site ID] SET tblGalaxys.[A Site Name] = [Ceekay_site].[site_name], tblGalaxys.A Site Region] = IIf([Ceekay_site].[region]=1,"South",IIf([Ceekay_site].[region]=2,"Midlands",IIf([Ceekay_site].[region]=3 Or [Ceekay_site].[region]=4,"North"))), tblGalaxys.[A Site Area] = [WurzelSitesProgUpdate].[area], tblGalaxys.[A Site Programme] = [WurzelSitesProgUpdate].[technology type], tblGalaxys.[B Site Name] = [Ceekay_site_1].[site_name], tblGalaxys.[B Site Region] = IIf([Ceekay_site_1].[region]=1,"South",IIf([Ceekay_site_1].[region]=2,"Midlands",IIf([Ceekay_site_1].[region]=3 Or [Ceekay_site_1].[region]=4,"North"))), tblGalaxys.[B Site Area] = [WurzelSitesProgUpdate_1].[area], tblGalaxys.[B Site Programme] = [WurzelSitesProgUpdate_1].[technology type];
```

**update ML Number qryMakeTempMLNumber**

```
SELECT tblRadioDeinstalls.[TNE Number], SPECTRUM_LNK.ML_NUMBER, SPECTRUM_LNK.LINK_STATUS
INTO tempMLNumber
FROM ((SPECTRUM_LNK INNER JOIN SPECTRUM_NODE ON SPECTRUM_LNK.A_END_NODE_ID = SPECTRUM_NODE.NODE_ID) 
INNER JOIN SPECTRUM_NODE AS SPECTRUM_NODE_1 ON SPECTRUM_LNK.B_END_NODE_ID = SPECTRUM_NODE_1.NODE_ID) 
INNER JOIN tblRadioDeinstalls ON (tblRadioDeinstalls.[A Site ID] = SPECTRUM_NODE.SITE_ID) AND (SPECTRUM_NODE_1.SITE_ID = tblRadioDeinstalls.[B Site ID])
WHERE (((SPECTRUM_LNK.LINK_TYPE)="R"));
```

**qryUpdateMLNumber**

```
UPDATE tblRadioDeinstalls INNER JOIN tempMLNumber ON tblRadioDeinstalls.[TNE Number] =
tempMLNumber.[TNE Number] SET tblRadioDeinstalls.[ML number] = [ML_NUMBER],
tblRadioDeinstalls.[Link Status] = [LINK_STATUS];
```

**update ML Number qryMakeTempMLNumber**

```
SELECT Galaxys.[TNE Number], Ceekay_LNK.ML_NUMBER, Ceekay _LNK.LINK_STATUS
INTO tempMLNumber
FROM ((Ceekay _LNK INNER JOIN Ceekay _NODE ON Ceekay _LNK.A_END_NODE_ID = Ceekay _NODE.NODE_ID) 
INNER JOIN Ceekay _NODE AS Ceekay _NODE_1 ON Ceekay _LNK.B_END_NODE_ID = Ceekay _NODE_1.NODE_ID) 
INNER JOIN tblGalaxys ON (tblGalaxys.[A Site ID] = Ceekay_NODE.SITE_ID) AND (Ceekay _NODE_1.SITE_ID = tblGalaxys.[B Site ID])
WHERE (((Ceekay_LNK.LINK_TYPE)="R"));
```

**qryUpdateMLNumber**

```
UPDATE tblGalaxys INNER JOIN tempMLNumber ON tblGalaxys.[TNE Number] =
tempMLNumber.[TNE Number] SET tblGalaxys.[ML number] = [ML_NUMBER],
tblGalaxys.[Link Status] = [LINK_STATUS];
```

The request is to populate the above in sql database using sql query langauage.

Can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have all the pieces there. Try the update like this:

```
UPDATE tblRadioDeinstalls 
  SET tblRadioDeinstalls.[ML number] = [ML_NUMBER],
  tblRadioDeinstalls.[Link Status] = [LINK_STATUS]
FROM tblRadioDeinstalls 
INNER JOIN tempMLNumber ON tblRadioDeinstalls.[TNE Number] =
tempMLNumber.[TNE Number] ;
```

Here is a link to documentation and examples for SQL Server Updates http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8hwekas8(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use aliases in update statements, this makes it easier to read. Look at the test code below.

```
DECLARE @tableA TABLE
    (
     id INT
    ,MyData VARCHAR(20)
    );

INSERT INTO @tableA VALUES (0,'First Element'), (1,'Second Element'), (2, 'Fourth Element')

SELECT * FROM @tableA

UPDATE A
SET a.MyData = 'Third Element'
FROM @tableA AS A
WHERE a.id = 2;

SELECT * FROM @tableA
```

As you notice instead of `UPDATE @tableA AS A` I just did `UPDATE A` and defined `A` in `FROM` clause. In `UPDATE` statement `SET` always follows `UPDATE` than the rest of information.